# Есть ли возможность в T-SQL сделать IN по нескольким полям?

Tags: sql-server

Вот минимально воспроизводимый пример, допустим я хочу узнать последние цены, но на определённую дату

Сейчас я делаю так, но это не красиво, и ресурсоёмко наверняка, конвертировать все поля

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [OtherID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SomeDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Price] [real] NOT NULL
) 

insert into Test values
(1,'01.01.2010',50),
(1,'02.01.2010',100),
(1,'01.01.2011',200),

(2,'01.01.2010',150),
(2,'01.02.2010',300),

(3,'01.03.2010',15),
(3,'01.02.2012',55)


declare @Date date
Set @Date='2010-07-04'
SELECT * from Test where (CAST([SomeDate]as char)+CAST([OtherID] as char))
IN(
SELECT CAST(MAX([SomeDate])as char)+CAST([OtherID] as char) FROM dbo.Test
    WHERE @Date<=[SomeDate]
    GROUP BY [OtherID]
)
```

А хотелось бы так

```
declare @Date date
Set @Date='2010-07-04'
SELECT * from Test where ([SomeDate],[OtherID])
IN(
SELECT MAX([SomeDate]),[OtherID]  FROM dbo.Test
    WHERE @Date<=[SomeDate]
    GROUP BY [OtherID]
)
```

Гугл говорит что у MY-SQL с этим нет проблем, а что насчёт T-SQL ?

P.S. своей ID у таблицы нет и добавить нельзя, иначе было бы куда проще

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не понимаю зачем так усложнять когда есть оконные функции, я рекомендую познакомиться с ними получше, так как они облегчают сложные запросы типа таких.

```
WITH [Data] AS (
SELECT 
  *, 
  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [OtherID] order by [SomeDate] desc) AS ROW_NUMBER
FROM Test 
WHERE @Date <= [SomeDate]
)
SELECT 
      [Data].* 
FROM [Data] 
WHERE 
     ROW_NUMBER = 1;
```

не нужно ничего конвертировать просто пронумеровать по группе отсортировать и вывести первую.
Ссылка на [фидл](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/67ea2/21)

послесловие.

условие типа

```
([SomeDate],[OtherID])
IN(
SELECT MAX([SomeDate]),[OtherID]  FROM dbo.Test
    WHERE @Date<=[SomeDate]
    GROUP BY [OtherID]
)
```

не гарантирует желаемый ответ в случае если у вас на один день несколько цен и это место потенциальной ошибки.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, вроде то что нужно, но нельзя ли этот ROW_NUMBER не выводимым сделать, допустим у меня очень много полей, и вручную прописывать все, кроме ROW_NUMBER не хотелось бы

Comment: Можно. Соедините с тест и выведите только его поля. Только нужно уникальное поле для соединения

Comment: Хороший ответ. +1 с моей стороны.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky ты у меня в линкедин в контакте. Благодарю

Comment: @AzizUmarov. Абсолютно. Нам нужно ценить и продвигать хорошие ответы.